# How to prevent MP3s from being downloaded?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo, audio-player

I'm on project to construct an online music site at the final stage of delivery. The MP3 audio files are openly available to download via browser inspector (absolute paths to the audio files). How can I secure them from being downloaded,  yet still available to stream in a browser?

Are there any high level encryption policies to stop them from being downloaded?

Technologies used:
Angular.JS, Node.JS on Sails.JS.

Please suggest to me some solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is saw a thread with nearly the same question maybe that one can help you. [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222532/protect-audio-file-from-being-downloaded-while-still-being-playable-through-jque) I hope this will help you

Comment: by having usage policy and great lawyers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The post you suggested to use oAuth or hyperlink is no longer available for second time. Any ideas on how to implement them on Angular JS/Node JS environment?