# How to mask an embedded audio file from being seen and downloaded from dev tools?

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio, piracy-prevention

For a small website I am creating, I have an embedded piece of audio which plays on the landing screen, the current method I am using is just by simply embedding it via standard html:

```
<audio autoplay loop id="player" src="audio1.wav"></audio>
```

The issue with this method is it is possible to find and download the src when looking in devtools. I want to mask the src so nobody can find it and download it, as the audio is up for sale/copyrighted.

Is there a method where the original .wav audio file cannot be traced back and downloaded?

Comment: Try Googling: "DRM". To prevent downloading is an oxymoron, the very act of browsing is downloading content of a site so it's cached. The trick is to make the file itself secured even if it's completely downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real way to prevent someone from obtaining the audio in one way or another if they're determined enough. However, a few alternatives are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222532/protect-audio-file-from-being-downloaded-while-still-being-playable-through-jque), with some more concrete code examples [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jplayer/s0peuxn1PnQ). Consider only playing a small sampler to prevent someone from getting the entire audio clip.